# How to add actionbar-pulltorefresh library without gradle?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I need to add this library

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

to an android application in Eclipse without using gradle.

Exporting the project as a jar is not working.

Adding it as a project dependency doesn't work also.

`12-07 21:32:27.190: E/dalvikvm(17102): Could not find class 'uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout', referenced from method com.icoldo.mobile.android.qgroups.ViewNewsItemActivity.onCreate`

Comment: First, you will need to clone the project to your local repo, and import it to your Eclipse. Then, right click the project that want to add this library, and choose `Properties`->`Android`, see the `Library` section, and click `Add`, to add the library.

Comment: @Wenhui - thanks it works.. in order to port the application how should i proceed? should i add the project library (pull to refresh) inside my project? would this work? i need to be able to clone to another pc and work

Comment: In that case, I will create a folder (let's named it "MyProject") thats contains your project and all the libraries, and push MyProject to your remote repo, so when you want to port it to your other machine, you clone MyProject to your local repo, and import all your libraries projects to Eclipse ( assuming you are using Eclipse ), then lastly your own project.

Comment: If you don't change anything in the library, you can simply clone the library to your other system. In this case I write a tiny shell script with the clone commands for the libraries. I push the script and the project.properties for dependencies to the remote repo.

Comment: @Wenhui - answer if you want accept

Comment: Post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, I will create a folder (let's named it "MyProject") thats contains your project and all the libraries, and push MyProject to your remote repo, so when you want to port it to your other machine, you clone MyProject to your local repo, and import all your libraries projects to Eclipse ( assuming you are using Eclipse ), then lastly your own project.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all the files in your project tree, if you don't want that, and you want to keep it in an different project in Eclipse, you can create a new project in Eclipse and add the files to the tree, mark it as a library, build it with ant, it will generate the jar which you should be able to use after in your project. I used the first option and it works, I'm thinking to switch to the second option though.